# About the super() function

Tags: python, pyqt, maya

I'm using QtDesign to create my own UI and convert it to python version. So after subclass the UI python file, i had written some function to implement mouseEvent for QGraphicsView. Just one small question. How can i call the super() function for the QGraphicsView?

```
class RigModuleUi(QtGui.QMainWindow,Ui_RiggingModuleUI):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        super(RigModuleUi,self).__init__(parent = parent)
    self.GraphicsView.mousePressEvent = self.qView_mousePressEvent

    def qView_mousePressEvent(self,event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            super(RigModuleUi,self).mousePressEvent(event)
```

Look like the `super(RigModuleUi,self).mousePressEvent(event)`will return the mouseEvent for QMainWindow, not QGraphicsView. So all other option for mouse like rubberBand will lost.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is `self.GraphicsView`? A `QGraphicsView` instance? Because by your comment to Eevee's answer it's *definitely* not an instance of `QGraphicsView`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you expect to happen here.  You're storing a *bound method*.  When it's called, it'll still be called with the same `self` it had when you stored it.

Your `super` is walking up the ancestry of `RigModuleUi`, which doesn't inherit from `QGraphicsView`.

`self.GraphicsView` is a funny name for an instance attribute; is that supposed to be the name of a class, or is it just capitalized incidentally?  (Please follow [PEP8 naming conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).)  Perhaps you'd have more luck if you defined the method as a global function and assigned *that* to the instance.

```
def qView_mousePressEvent(self, event):
    if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
        super(QGraphicsView, self).mousePressEvent(event)

class RigModuleUi(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_RiggingModuleUI):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(RigModuleUi,self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.GraphicsView.mousePressEvent = qView_mousePressEvent
```

Guessing wildly here; I don't know PyQt's class hierarchy  :)

Comment: TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

This is what i had try

`super(QtGui.QGraphicsView, self.GraphicsView).mousePressEvent(event)`
But still, its not working....
Btw, self.GraphicsView is name of QGraphicsView object i had created in QtDesign, and thank for the link you gave me :D

Comment: are you using `reload()`, or other funny module-loading tricks?  those can screw up `super()`.